# Docusignapi admin api for getting/setting user identity provider

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am looking for DocuSign admin api to get or set user identity provider. Can someone please help me with that.not sure of there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the reference for the [GET operation](https://developers.docusign.com/orgadmin-api/reference/IdentityProviders/IdentityProviders/getIdentityProviders) but it appears there's no way to set them through the API at this time.

You do that with:

```
GET /v2/organizations/{organizationId}/identity_providers
```

Comment: But I want to get identity provider of specific user . This will get all the identity provider of organization. I want to get the user identity provider.

Comment: are you saying different users in the same account/org can have different identity providers? are you sure?

Comment: maybe you want to know how a specific user logged in, but AFAIK this is not available right now in the API

Comment: I want to check if the user idp ( identity provider) is set or not (default). So incase if the user idp (identity provider) is not set I can set it for that user.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "set it". If you mean set it such that this user CAN use the IDP, that's an account level setting, not per-user. If you mean you want to actually go to the IDP to set that user, that depends on your IDP. If you mean you want to actually log in the user via the IDP - I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Thanks @inbar gazit it was a nice and helpful info.